# Adding date as parameter

Tags: excel, vba

in below vba code, how to parameterized "09-Oct-18" and file name should be _.xlsx from a sheet in excel 2016.

```
column A date; column B filename
09-Oct-18      CATEGORY_99_TAS_09-10-2018.xlsx
15-Oct-18      CATEGORY_99_TAS_15-10-2018.xlsx
```

Code:

```
If Format(Range("A" & i).Value, "d-mmm-yy") = "09-Oct-18" Then
Range("B" & i).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(R2C1,'D:\test\files\[CATEGORY_99_TAS_09-10-2018.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R30C2,2,FALSE)"

Else
   If Format(Range("A" & i).Value, "d-mmm-yy") = "15-Oct-18" Then
    Range("B" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(R2C1,'D:\test\files\[CATEGORY_99_TAS_15-10-2018.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R30C2,2,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what this part should do... so I guess you want to check that the date in column A match the date in sheet name in column b:

```
If Format(Range("A" & i).Value, "d-mmm-yy") = Format(CDate("18-Oct-15"), "d-mmm-yy") Then
```

Based on your comment I think this might work. If you have a date in column A and then a sheet name in column B, the macro code will see if the date in column A is equal to the date in the sheet name. If they are equal it will print the formula you can see in B2. Otherwise it will jump to next row.
[image]

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim FileNameVal As String
Dim FileNameDate As String
Dim YearVal As Integer
Dim MonthVal As Integer
Dim DayVal As Integer
Dim DateCorrect As Date

For i = 2 To 10 'Start loop from row 2 to 10, where every step is row (i)

On Error GoTo Handler 'If cell is empty, then go to Handler:
    FileNameVal = Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "B")).Value 'Take value in Column  B and row i.
    If FileNameVal = "" Then 'If cell is empty then go to Handler2:
        On Error GoTo HandlerPart2
    Else
    FileNameDate = Split((Split(Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "B")).Value, ".xlsx")(0)), "CATEGORY_99_TAS_")(1) 'Split out the date in the filename
    YearVal = Right(FileNameDate, 4) 'Find Year
    MonthVal = Mid(FileNameDate, 4, 2) 'Find Month
    DayVal = Left(FileNameDate, 2) 'Find Day
    DateCorrect = DateSerial(YearVal, MonthVal, DayVal) 'Rearrange date from dd/mm/yyy -> yyyy/mm/dd

        If Format(Range("A" & i).Value, "d-mmm-yy") = Format(CDate(DateCorrect), "d-mmm-yy") Then 'Compare the date in column A with the date in column b (date in sheet name), if they are equal then
            Range("B" & i).Select 'Select column B and row (i), (this will overwrite the sheet name, I would suggest to use column D)
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=VLOOKUP(R2C1,'D:\test\files\[" & FileNameVal & "]Sheet1'!R2C1:R30C2,2,FALSE)" ' Print out vlookup formula based on the sheetname.

        Else
Handler:
HandlerPart2:
        'Do Nothing
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: the date should not be hardcoded.. but it should read date & file name from the parameter sheet

Comment: I not sure I understand :), Do you want to compare the date in Column A with the date in the sheet name (column B), so example: compare Column A: "09-Oct-18" with the date part in Column B: 15-10-2018 (excluding CATEGORY_99_TAS_   and the file .xlsx)?

Comment: sorry if english not gud.. currently, I hv to open ze macro and change the date & file name in above code. But i want to create a new sheet where will enter the date in row A2, fileName in B2 and will hv a btn tht wen click will call the macro and put the A2& B2 cells data in it..

Comment: Is ok! :). I like the challange of question and problems, hope the code might work in your favour.